# Xpath - matching based on node() contains() content

Tags: ruby, xpath

I have the following HTML structure (there are many blocks using the same architecture):

```
<span id="mySpan">
  <i>
    Price
    <b>
       3 900
       <small>€</small>
    </b>
  </i>
</span>
```

Now, I want to get the content of `<b>` using Xpath which I tried like so:

```
//span[@id="mySpan"]/i/node()[1][contains(text(),"Price")]
```

which does match anything. How can I match this using the `node()[1]` text as anchor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the Xpath you tried, instead of `text()` which return *text node child*, simply use `.` :

```
//span[@id="mySpan"]/i/node()[1][contains(.,"Price")]
```

For the ultimate goal, I'd suggest this XPath :

```
//span[@id="mySpan"]/i[contains(.,"Price")]/b
```

or if you want specifically to match against the *first node* within `<i>` :

```
//span[@id="mySpan"]/i[contains(node(),"Price")]/b
```